# Android disable click on listview item while scrolling the list

Tags: android, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener, horizontallist

I have a main activity and a adapter. 
The activity contains an on touch listener which is defined on a listview. 
The adapter contains onclick listner for the listview 'item'.
When i scroll this list, it works fine, however on releasing the finger (which is ACTION_UP motion event) my list item is clicked and thus opens a new activity (as i have placed an intent over the click)

how can i disable the item click when im scrolling the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the scroll listener to your listview and when it stops scrolling make isScrolling flag to false.Now when you perform item click you just need to check the flag isScrolling and you are done.

See the below code.Hope it will help.Thanks

```
listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                isScrolling = false;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
           isScrolling = true;
        }
    });

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            if(!isScrolling){
                //start your activity
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: In my case its a HorizontalListView which extends AdapterView<ListAdapter>, Hence i'm not getting setonscrolllistener

Comment: check HorizontalListView.java file.there must be these methods overridden.make a public boolean variable there.

Answer (score 0):

set [OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html)

```
setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        clickAvailable = false;
    }

    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        if (scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
            clickAvailable = true;
        }
    }
});

...
//In OnClickListener
if(clickAvailable) {
//do your work
}
...
```

Answer (score -1):

For the click event to get triggered put the code(starting a new activity) inside setOnItemClickListener

```
hlv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Abc.this,Xyz.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

where hlv is your horizontal list view object. Then the scroll event won't get mixed with click event.